# How to pick multiple fasta sequences from a genes list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files

The gene list file looks like this

```
LOC_Os06g12230.1
Pavir.Ab03005
Pavir.J14065
ChrUn.fgenesh
Sevir.1G325700
LOC_Os02g51280.1
Bradi3g59320
Brast04G017400
```

Fasta sequence file looks like this

```
>LOC_Os03g57190.1 pacid=33130570 polypeptide=LOC_Os03g57190.1 locus=LOC_Os03g57190 ID=LOC_Os03g57190.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGGAGGCGGCGGTGGGGGACGGGGAAGGCGGTGGCGGCGGCGGCGGGCGGGGGAAGCGTGGGCGGGGAGGAGGAGGAGG
GGAGATGGTGGAGGCGGTGTGGGGGCAGACGGGGAGTACGGCGTCGCGGATCTACAGGGTGAGGGCGACGGGGGGGAAGG
ACAGGCACAGCAAGGTGTACACGGCGAAGGGAATCCGCGACCGCCGCGTCCGCCTCTCCGTCGCCACCGCCATCCAGTTC
TACGACCTCCAGGACCGCCTCGGCTTCGACCAGCCGAGCAAGGCCATCGAGTGG
>LOC_Os02g51280.1 pacid=33134358 polypeptide=LOC_Os02g51280.1 locus=LOC_Os02g51280 ID=LOC_Os02g51280.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGACCATGGACGTCGCCGGAGACGCCGGAGGTGGCCGCCGCCCAAACTTCCCCTTGCAGCTTCTTGAGAAGAAGGAGGA
CGGGCGGTGCCGGAGGGGAGATGCAGCTGCGGAAGGCGGCGCCGAAGCGGAGCTCCACCAAGGACCGGCACACCAAGGTG
GAAGGGAGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGCTGTGCGCGGCGAGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTGG
>LOC_Os06g12230.1 pacid=33145596 polypeptide=LOC_Os06g12230.1 locus=LOC_Os06g12230 ID=LOC_Os06g12230.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGGATGTCACCGGAGACGGCGGAGGAGGAGGGCAACGGCCCAATTTCCCCCTGCAGCTCCTCGGGAAGAAGGAGGAGCA
GACGTGCTCGACGTCGCAGACTGCCGGGGCGGGCGGCGGCGGCGTCGTGGGCGCGAATGGGTCGGCGGCGGCGGCGCCGC
CGAAGCGGACGTCGACGAAGGACCGGCACACGAAGGTGGACGGGCGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGATCTGCGCC
GCGCGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTCGGGCACAAGACCGACGGCGA
>LOC_Os05g43760.1 pacid=33158388 polypeptide=LOC_Os05g43760.1 locus=LOC_Os05g43760 ID=LOC_Os05g43760.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGACAAGCAATAACAGCACGAATGAGGAGCTCGGCGGCGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGGCCGACAAGCCGAGCGGCGGCGGCGG
CGCCGCCGCCGCCGTGGCGAGCTCGCGGCACTGGTCGGCGTCGACGGAGTCGCGGATCGTGCGCGTGTCGAGGGTGTTCG
GCGGCAAGGACCGTCACAGCAAGGTGAGGACGGTGAAGGGGCTCCGCGACCGGCGGGTGCGGCTGTCGGTGCCGACGGCG
ATCCAGCTCTACGACCTGCAGGACCGGCTGGGGCTCAGCCAGCCGAGCAAGGTGGTCGACT
```

if the **gene name** and **header line** matches then, sequence has to be pulled out into new file

new file should contain

```
>LOC_Os02g51280.1 pacid=33134358 polypeptide=LOC_Os02g51280.1 locus=LOC_Os02g51280 ID=LOC_Os02g51280.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGACCATGGACGTCGCCGGAGACGCCGGAGGTGGCCGCCGCCCAAACTTCCCCTTGCAGCTTCTTGAGAAGAAGGAGGA
CGGGCGGTGCCGGAGGGGAGATGCAGCTGCGGAAGGCGGCGCCGAAGCGGAGCTCCACCAAGGACCGGCACACCAAGGTG
GAAGGGAGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGCTGTGCGCGGCGAGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTGG
>LOC_Os06g12230.1 pacid=33145596 polypeptide=LOC_Os06g12230.1 locus=LOC_Os06g12230 ID=LOC_Os06g12230.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGGATGTCACCGGAGACGGCGGAGGAGGAGGGCAACGGCCCAATTTCCCCCTGCAGCTCCTCGGGAAGAAGGAGGAGCA
GACGTGCTCGACGTCGCAGACTGCCGGGGCGGGCGGCGGCGGCGTCGTGGGCGCGAATGGGTCGGCGGCGGCGGCGCCGC
CGAAGCGGACGTCGACGAAGGACCGGCACACGAAGGTGGACGGGCGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGATCTGCGCC
GCGCGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTCGGGCACAAGACCGACGGCGA
```

I had tried like this

```
grep -f genelist.txt -A3 fastafile.txt >> newfasta.txt
```

but different fasta sequences have different lengths,

After pattern match, i want to pick till next '>' symbol appears

Comment: wrt `if the gene name and header line matches` - how do you define a match? I assume the "header line" is the one that starts with `>` so does the "gene name" have to be the first "word" after the `>` or can it appear anywhere on that line or in some specific contexts? Are you looking for a string match or a regexp match? Partial word or full word matches only?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
/^>/{
  found=""
}
($2 in a){
  found=1
}
found
' Input_file_gene FS="[> ]" Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
>LOC_Os02g51280.1 pacid=33134358 polypeptide=LOC_Os02g51280.1 locus=LOC_Os02g51280 ID=LOC_Os02g51280.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGACCATGGACGTCGCCGGAGACGCCGGAGGTGGCCGCCGCCCAAACTTCCCCTTGCAGCTTCTTGAGAAGAAGGAGGA
CGGGCGGTGCCGGAGGGGAGATGCAGCTGCGGAAGGCGGCGCCGAAGCGGAGCTCCACCAAGGACCGGCACACCAAGGTG
GAAGGGAGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGCTGTGCGCGGCGAGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTGG
>LOC_Os06g12230.1 pacid=33145596 polypeptide=LOC_Os06g12230.1 locus=LOC_Os06g12230 ID=LOC_Os06g12230.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
ATGGATGTCACCGGAGACGGCGGAGGAGGAGGGCAACGGCCCAATTTCCCCCTGCAGCTCCTCGGGAAGAAGGAGGAGCA
GACGTGCTCGACGTCGCAGACTGCCGGGGCGGGCGGCGGCGGCGTCGTGGGCGCGAATGGGTCGGCGGCGGCGGCGCCGC
CGAAGCGGACGTCGACGAAGGACCGGCACACGAAGGTGGACGGGCGGGGGCGGCGCATCCGGATGCCGGCGATCTGCGCC
GCGCGGGTGTTCCAGCTGACGCGGGAGCTCGGGCACAAGACCGACGGCGA
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to process FASTA files with awk, is to build up a variable called `name` and a variable called `seq`. Every time you read a full sequence, you can process it. Remark that, for the best way of processing, the sequence, should be stored as a continues string, and not contain any newlines or whitespaces due. A generic awk for processing fasta, looks like this:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { process_sequence_here }
     /^>/{name=$0; seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence_here }' file.fasta
```

You can make this a bit easier by introducing a couple of functions:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { process_sequence(name_seq) }
     /^>/{name=substr($0,2); seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence(name,seq) }

     BEGIN{seq_ere=sprintf("%80s","");gsub(" ",".",seq_ere) }
     function print_sequence(name,seq) {
         gsub(seq_ere,"&" ORS, seq); print ">" name ORS seq
     }
     function process_sequence(name,seq) { ... }
    ' file.fasta
```

In case of the OP, the above would read:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { a[$0]; next }
     /^>/ && seq { process_sequence(name_seq) }
     /^>/{name=substr($0,2); seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence(name,seq) }

     BEGIN{seq_ere=sprintf("%80s","");gsub(" ",".",seq_ere) }
     function print_sequence(name,seq) {
         gsub(seq_ere,"&" ORS, seq); print ">" name ORS seq
     }
     function process_sequence(name,seq) {
         $0=name; if ($1 in a) print_sequence (name,seq)
     }
    ' list.txt file.fasta
```

When you process fasta-files with awk, you can always concider to use [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk). It has all the bells-and-whistles from POSIX awk, but is augmented to easily process FASTA files:

> **Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
>   by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
>   (Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
>   . I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^LOC.*/s##/>&/bb#p' file1 |
sed -n -e ':a' -f - -e 'b;:b;p;n;/^>/ba;bb' file2
```

Use `file1` to *grep* for the keys in `file2`. If a key matches, print that line and all following lines until a new key. Repeat.

Alternative using GNU parallel and grep:

```
parallel -k --pipe -N1 --recstart '>' --cat <file2 \
  'grep -F LOC file1 | grep -qFf - -m1 {} && cat {}'
```

Another way using csplit, parallel and grep:

```
csplit -z file2 '/^>/' '{*}'
parallel -k 'grep -wqFf file1 -m1 {} && cat {}' ::: xx?? > outFile
rm xx??
```

Comment: Very nice ... it's a way of using sed that I was not aware of!

Comment: Does this not require that the files are "sorted" in the same way?

Comment: The order is determined by `file2` i.e. `file2` is filtered by matches on `file1`.